# List all files without 775 or 777 permissions

Tags: permissions, find

How can I list all files without 777 or 775 file permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find <some dirs> \! \( -perm 0777 -o -perm 0775 \)
```

Comment: Is this listing all files without these permissions, or all files with these permissions... it seems like it's with these permissions...

Comment: The `!` reverses the following predicate.

Comment: Wouldn't this specification not take into account SGID, SUID, and items marked with the sticky bit?

Comment: @mdpc: Sure, but those aren't really "775" or "777" either.